# Devise validate presence of username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, devise

I am trying to add a `name` field to my devise user model. I have run the migration and updated the devise params:

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name]) 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end
```

And added the name field to `registrations#edit`:

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, autocomplete: "name" %>
```

The problem occurs in the edit action of the registration controller. I want all users to have usernames, so I added the following validation:
`validates :name, presence: true`

However, if a user is only updating his email I get a `Name cannot be blank` error. I changed the validation to only validate presence `on: :create`. This is also problematic because if a user does not enter a name when updating his account, his account is saved with the name being blank. I know there is a simple solution. How can I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried making the validation conditional on `if: :name_changed?` ?

Comment: Could clarify your requirements? I am not sure I got it:
1. When creating a new account, name must exist.
2. When updating, name must exist or depends on other conditions?

Comment: I ended up solving it by setting a default value in the name field. Thanks anyway